# Difference in seconds between server time and timestamp in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display the difference, in seconds, between the current server time and a DATETIME (defined as 2012-01-01 00:00:01) entry in my database on a php page. I'm only wanting to display the difference for the latest entry.

I have been able to get some results, but I know the results aren't correct. If anyone is able to assist, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: I accidentally deleted what I had, but basically I was getting the current date/time and subtracting it from the row date_added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as:-

```
echo time() - strtotime('2012-01-01 00:00:01');
```

[time()](http://www.php.net/time)  [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime)

Comment: how would I get rid of the int() around the result when showing it?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up changing it to `echo time() - strtotime($row['date_added']);`

Comment: Instead of starting a new question, what would be the best option to add my `date_added` and another row called `date_mil` together and then get the time difference. The only problem is the `date_mil` is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, '2012-01-01 00:00:01', current_timestamp) as date_diff
```